# Mocha and relative paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

My code is component-based and tests reside directly in the components folder. Some components rely on files (or other resources), like the `ConfigurationManager` component:

```
class ConfigurationManager {
    constructor(protected configDir = 'config') { }

    addResource(file) {
        let fileUri = path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), this.configDir, file);
        let configuration = require(fileUri);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `config` directory is in the root directory of the project, hence `fileUri` makes sense here. But when running the tests (`mocha -r ts-node/register src/Components/**/Tests/*Test.ts`) it fails, since the root directory isn't the project root anymore but the mocha directory within `node_modules`.

How to fix that?

Comment: I like to make a test dir off the root dir of my project and in that test directory create an index.js/ts that imports all my other component tests in the order I want them ran. I then mocha ./tests from my root dir.

Comment: That would mean I'd need to change my entire directory structure. Not the best solution :/

Comment: No... it requires the creation of one directory, with one file in it. This is a pretty standard way to chain component based unit tests.